# Display data from MYSQL into text field using AJAX and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, ajax

I want to display the array data that I have called in **getword.php** into the text field in **index.php** using **AJAX**. but how ?

this is the **index.php**

```
<body>
<div class="container" >
<h2>View data</h2>
<h4>Word List : </h4>   
    

        <div class="form-group">
            <input id="wordlist" type="text" class="form-control" name="wordlist">
            </div><br>
            <button id="display" title="Generate Word">Generate</button>
            <div class="input-single">
            </div>
    
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#display").click(function() {
            $.ajax({    
                type: "POST",
                url: "getword.php",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function($result){
                $('#wordlist').val('');
                }    
            });
      });
    })
    </script>
```

and this is the sql query to get data from database into array (**getword.php**)

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = ""; 
$dbname = "wordlist";

$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $dbname);
if (!$con) {
 die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "select kata from word"; 

 $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql); 
 $result = array(); 
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
    $result[]= $row[0];
 }
 echo json_encode(array('kata'=>$result));  
 mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: Whats the error now ?

Comment: The data is in the `$result` variable. Try a `console.log($result);` in the success handler.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you write PHP code as below it will be lot more simple

```
<?php
   $host = "localhost";
   $user = "root";
   $password = ""; 
   $dbname = "wordlist";
   $con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $dbname);
   if (!$con) {
     die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
   }
   $sql = "SELECT kata FROM word"; 
   $res = $con->query($sql); 
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
      $dataToSend = $row[0];
   }
   mysqli_close($con);
  
   echo json_encode($dataToSend);  
?>
```

Now the script be like this to place the result in the text box

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "getword.php",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function($result) {
    var val = JSON.parse($result);
    console.log(val); // see console in browser to check what is sent back
    var txtBox = docuent.getElementById('wordlist');
    txtBox.value = val;
  }
});
```

Here I guess the data from the PHP file will be a single value since you are using a single text box. if multiple values are there then use an array to store data in PHP and send it in json_encode() itself.
hope that this becomes helpful to you.